# How to use ROW_NUMBER() - but instead of incremental numbers , generate A, B, C, D, E

Tags: postgresql

I'm using ROW_NUMBER() to generate incremetal IDs numbers like this

```
 ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY ProductDate) as ID
```

i.e.

1
2
3
4

How can I do the same but create Alphabetic ordered letters like this
A
B
C
D
E
F.
..... AA, BB, CC

any ideas?  Thx in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a character sequence on postgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55816664/creating-a-character-sequence-on-postgresql) Also see [Postgres - How to create an alphanumeric sequence like AAAA0000 and so on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46075811/postgres-how-to-create-an-alphanumeric-sequence-like-aaaa0000-and-so-on)

Comment: thx, Yes and No.. how do I create function to do this, what is the code?  I need call the function from my existing query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a3006e45ceb93c1e4e465a5651fbd523)

You need to write an own function like this ([original source](https://gist.github.com/pozs/bd461063489eeca58703)):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION number_to_base(num BIGINT, base INTEGER)
  RETURNS TEXT
  LANGUAGE sql
  IMMUTABLE
  STRICT
AS $function$
WITH RECURSIVE n(i, n, r) AS (
    SELECT -1, num - 1, 0
  UNION ALL
    SELECT i + 1, n / base, (n % base)::INT
    FROM n
    WHERE n > 0
)

SELECT string_agg(ch, '')
FROM (
  SELECT chr(ascii('A') + r) ch
  FROM n
  WHERE i >= 0
  ORDER BY i DESC
) ch

$function$;
```

It converts the numeral radix from base 10 to base 26 and replace the numbers 0-25 with A to Z. It's not quite perfect but a quick sketch (e.g. the A is 0 at the moment, you need to adjust it a bit).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the the functions Chr() and Ascii() together to increment a character. The only other complication is determining when the next value is '...AA' instead a incrementing the last letter (i.e 'AY' => 'AZ' while    'AZ' => 'AAA). So try:

```
create or replace function alpha_sequence_next_val( alpha_seq_in text)
returns text
  language sql
  immutable
as $$                  
select case when alpha_seq_in is null 
              or alpha_seq_in = ''
                 then 'A'
                 
            when substr(alpha_seq_in, length(alpha_seq_in), 1) = 'Z'
                 then concat(substr(alpha_seq_in,1,length(alpha_seq_in)-1 ), 'AA')
                 
            else (substr(alpha_seq_in, 1,length(alpha_seq_in)-1)) ||  
                  chr(ascii(substr(alpha_seq_in, length(alpha_seq_in)))+1)             
       end;                 
$$;
```

Test:

```
do $$
declare 
  seq_value  text; 
begin
   for test_seq in 0 .. 26*3
   loop 
      seq_value = alpha_sequence_next_val(seq_value);
      raise notice 'Next Sequence==> %', seq_value;
   end loop; 
end;
$$;
```